# Reserved structure member in CMSIS device peripheral access file

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, cmsis

Why in the CMSIS device file `"TM4C123GH6PM.h"` there are reserved structure members declared in some of the peripheral's structures for example in `TIMER0_Type` structure there are two reserved members.
does it have something to do with the microcontroller itself or is it concerned with word alignment and how the structure is going to be allocated in the memory?

```
    typedef struct {                                    /*!< TIMER0 Structure                                                      */
  __IO uint32_t  CFG;                               /*!< GPTM Configuration                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t  TAMR;                              /*!< GPTM Timer A Mode                                                     */
  __IO uint32_t  TBMR;                              /*!< GPTM Timer B Mode                                                     */
  __IO uint32_t  CTL;                               /*!< GPTM Control                                                          */
  __IO uint32_t  SYNC;                              /*!< GPTM Synchronize                                                      */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED;
  __IO uint32_t  IMR;                               /*!< GPTM Interrupt Mask                                                   */
  __IO uint32_t  RIS;                               /*!< GPTM Raw Interrupt Status                                             */
  __IO uint32_t  MIS;                               /*!< GPTM Masked Interrupt Status                                          */
  __O  uint32_t  ICR;                               /*!< GPTM Interrupt Clear                                                  */
  __IO uint32_t  TAILR;                             /*!< GPTM Timer A Interval Load                                            */
  __IO uint32_t  TBILR;                             /*!< GPTM Timer B Interval Load                                            */
  __IO uint32_t  TAMATCHR;                          /*!< GPTM Timer A Match                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t  TBMATCHR;                          /*!< GPTM Timer B Match                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t  TAPR;                              /*!< GPTM Timer A Prescale                                                 */
  __IO uint32_t  TBPR;                              /*!< GPTM Timer B Prescale                                                 */
  __IO uint32_t  TAPMR;                             /*!< GPTM TimerA Prescale Match                                            */
  __IO uint32_t  TBPMR;                             /*!< GPTM TimerB Prescale Match                                            */
  __IO uint32_t  TAR;                               /*!< GPTM Timer A                                                          */
  __IO uint32_t  TBR;                               /*!< GPTM Timer B                                                          */
  __IO uint32_t  TAV;                               /*!< GPTM Timer A Value                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t  TBV;                               /*!< GPTM Timer B Value                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t  RTCPD;                             /*!< GPTM RTC Predivide                                                    */
  __IO uint32_t  TAPS;                              /*!< GPTM Timer A Prescale Snapshot                                        */
  __IO uint32_t  TBPS;                              /*!< GPTM Timer B Prescale Snapshot                                        */
  __IO uint32_t  TAPV;                              /*!< GPTM Timer A Prescale Value                                           */
  __IO uint32_t  TBPV;                              /*!< GPTM Timer B Prescale Value                                           */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED1[981];
  __IO uint32_t  PP;                                /*!< GPTM Peripheral Properties                                            */
} TIMER0_Type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that particular part there is a 981 word gap between `TIMER0_TBPV` and `TIMER0_PP`, and a 1 word (32bit) gap between `TIMER0_SYNC` and `TIMER0_IMR`.  From the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms376e/spms376e.pdf?ts=1658750650264):

[image]

The "reserved" fields simply force alignment with the hardware register map for which the type is used as an overlay.  You certainly should not instantiate an object of this type in memory!

Comment: if each register is defined as a bitfield in the structure will it give the same result?

Comment: @aymanmagdy SO is not a discussion forum, avoid asking follow-on questions in comments.  Post a new question where you can better explain what you are asking.   Bit field packing, alingment and ordering is implementation defined.  Where used for register bitfields it is generally via a header provided with the toolchain.  Best avoided in your own code if you want portability.

Answer (score 1):

These structs are defined for easier access to memory mapped peripheral registers.

Each register has a fixed absolute address. The struct layout needs to be carefully designed such that the base address of the struct plus the offset of the member within the struct results in the register address.

As the register addresses are only partially contiguous, gaps without registers must be filled with dummy struct members, named `RESERVEDxx`.

Answer (score 0):

They are a 1:1 map with the hardware. Say that you have only two registers:

- A @ 0x1000
- B @ 0x1004

You could define this struct:

```
struct {
  u32* Ar;
  u32* Br;
}regs;
```

And then assign manually the addresses:

```
struct regs myRegs;
myRegs.Ar = (u32*)0x1000;
myRegs.Br = (u32*)0x1004;
```

But doing this is error prone and also very long to do. What you can do, and what CMSIS does, is to define a struct with datatypes instead of pointers, knowing that the compiler will treat such structure as contiguous elements in the memory and will do pointer access for you.

```
struct {
  u32 Ar;
  u32 Br;
}regs;

struct regs* myRegsPtr = (struct regs*) 0x1000;
```

Now `myRegsPtr` holds the base address of the hardware register structure. Since now the C structure mimics the HW layout, accessing a member of the structure does exactly the pointer arithmetic you need for accessing the register you requested.

```
myRegs->Br; //This does 0x1000 + sizeof(all members before Br), reaching the correct offset.
```

Now back to your question. When we look at the datasheet we see this particular HW structure:

[image]
[image]

Can you spot the jump of 981*4 bytes? That is where you `RESERVED` area in your struct come from. In order to access the last register, the compiler must know that there are this amount of bytes to "jump".